# Enterprise Library reference error when opening a legacy project in vs2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, visual-studio-2015, enterprise-library

I have a legacy project that has the following references:
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data

When I build the project in vs2013 everything works fine.
When I try to build the project in vs2015 I get the following error:

```
Error   BC30652 Reference required to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' containing the type 'SerializableConfigurationSection'. Add one to your project.
```

Solution explorer says it is in the references so I don't understand.

Comment: Check the reference version in VS2015 and make sure it's 4.1.0.0, this would be my first step of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that vs2015 has better intellisense then vs2013. I have absolutely no idea how in vs2013 my project was building and working because there were missing references the entire time but vs2013 was somehow still building. I also had bad lines of code that vs2013 intellisense never caught.

My advice:
If you are upgrading an app from previous versions to vs2015 and have all kinds of reference and code errors there is always the chance that it is things that vs2013 never caught.

vs2015 intellisense is a lot better.